# Get Skype ID from Activity object Bot Framework V3

Tags: skype, botframework

In the previous version of the Microsoft Bot Framework (v1) we were able to get the Skype ID (username) from the Message object. I have now updated to V3 and can no longer get the Skype ID, it returns a random ID in the ID field and the Skype Users name.

I have already built the back end to use the Skype ID and don't want to change that.

Is there anyway to get to the Skype ID?

I did see this in the documentation `"In the V3 version of the API a user is represented by a unique user ID per bot (and not for example the Skype ID)."` But they didn't explain anything more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Much like Facebook, Skype now provides extra privacy to the user by providing a unique user ID per bot.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get around it? Are there API calls I need to make to get the Skype ID?

Comment: I don't believe there is any work around.   This is a privacy protection issue.  What is the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: Based on who the user is we return different results. Eg, we have 2 customers, A and B, and they ask to see the price of Product A. As customer A is on a different pricing tier we should show them a different price to that of customer B. But if I cant differentiate between the 2 it is not going to work.

Is the unique id they send through going to be the same all the time? If so then I have a workaround in my solution but if that keeps changing I am going to have an issue

Comment: @Jeffrey: you can ask them to authenticate to your backend system to detect their pricing tier.

Comment: @kienct89 Yes I can but I don't want them to have to do that every time they send a message, I wanted to store an encrypted version of their skype id so I already know who is sending a message. The pricing tier was just an example, we have multiple questions that we are expecting and they are all user specific in what is returned.

Does the unique id that comes through from the Activity object stay the same for each call from that user?

Comment: The unique ID per user will remain constant for the bot.  IT will only change if the user interacts with a different bot